# Not receiving Presence update events

Tags: javascript, typescript, discord, discord.js

I have the intent enabled in the Discord developer portal and declared in my `<Client>` instance. Discord application (the actual Discord client, not the bot) is detecting that my activity status is changing but the event callback doesn't get triggered. My bot is only in one server so doesn't require verification for the intent yet.

```js
    private readonly _client: Client = new Client({
        intents: [
            Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
            Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_PRESENCES,
            Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS,
        ],
    });
```

[image: Developer Portal Intent]
[image: Discord client detecting the activity]

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a problem with my Discord client itself, reloaded it with CTRL + R and it started working normally.

Answer (score -2):

```
private readonly _client: Client = new Client({
    intents: 32767,
});
```

Try to use it this way, if an error occurs, show the code that is pulling the member's activity